# Bash and Tab Auto-complete

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I recently put Fedora Core 15 on my system, and I've had a behaviour change that I can't figure out. Using Tab-Complete in the BASH shell works fine except when I use the $HOME variable.

If I type `cd $HOME/d`<kbd>TAB</kbd>, it will auto-complete to the proper directory (doc), but it also inserts a preceding `\`, so the result is `cd \$HOME/doc`. This then fails, as such a path does not exist.

The error is

> bash: cd: $HOME/doc: No such file or directory

If I don't use Tab-Complete it works, as $HOME still points to the proper directory. Where did this extra `\` come from, and how do I make it go away?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By issuing the command `complete` you'll get the list of all completion definitions. Then you can search the offending definition somewhere in `/etc/bash_completion` and `/etc/bash_completion.d`. There can be also some `.bash_completion` in your home directory. On my system the `$HOME` variable is completed properly, but then fails to complete anything.

Did you try to use `~` instead of `$HOME`? It's easier to type and it works as expected...

Answer (score 1):

There is an option for it

```
shopt -s direxpand
```

It didn't work on Bash 4.1 (this incompatible feature was added in BASH 4.2), so I used it as

```
[[ $BASH_VERSION =~ ^4.[2-9] ]] && shopt -s direxpand
```